# Reentrant Lock , busy waiting resolved by the new tryLock method

Tags: java, java-8, thread-safety, executorservice, reentrantlock

I was going through java doc description of **lockInterruptibly** method in **ReentrantLock** class. *My intention was to see if the threads waiting to acquire lock are getting interrupted*, may be I am doing it horribly wrong. I know there is an explicit way to call interrupt on Thread and it might be that executorService that I am using has wrapped that concept under it's API.

This behavior is seen with lock method as well

My purpose is to learn this concept in detail

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

public class LockInterruptibly extends Thread {

    static ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    static Lock lock1 = new java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock();

    public void methodA() {
        if (lock1.tryLock()) {

            try {
                lock1.lockInterruptibly();
                System.out.println("lock acquired by " + this.getName() + "  of method A");
                Thread.sleep(5000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                System.out.println("this thread " + this.getName() + " was interrupted");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(this.getName() + "failed to acquire lock");
        }
    }

    public void methodB() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Printed by " + this.getName() + " - " + i);
        }
        lock1.unlock();
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " is exiting at time " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        methodA();
        methodB();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable r = new Thread(new LockInterruptibly());
            es.submit(r);
        }
        System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}
```

Now look at the console output below : 
[console logs showing the relative order, when each thread acquires lock and releases it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTC0k.png)

My questions is: 
1)*Why is this interleaving behavior?*  **Why more than 1 thread are able to acquire lock** (at least according to console output) , it's almost like a recursive behavior of acquiring locks. or is it just because console output is not in sync with what is happening actually?
2) Has it something to do with executor's way of treating time consuming threads and is normal behavior?

Comment: Didn't read the whole code, but at first glance: `lock1` is an instance variable, and each object will get its own lock.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I think @markspace is right, lock1 should be static

Comment: After studying the code more, I think that is it.  There are 10 locks in this program, one for each `LockInterruptibly` object, and your question seems to imply that you expect there to be only one lock.  So try `static`, or inject the lock.  Also, thread `a` and `b` appear to be unused, could you remove them from the source listing if they aren't?

Comment: Got it , fixed it , analysing the new output of the program now .

Comment: `if (lock1.tryLock()) lock1.lockInterruptibly();` makes no sense. And you're unlocking without checking if you have the lock.

Comment: @shmosel : because If thread calls tryLock and gets false -> It will never be  in waiting to be interrupted??

Comment: `tryLock()` only returns true when it *succeeds*.

Comment: @shmosel : got your point, both of them! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments ! I was reading about the new Lock api and how you can try to lock before actually 'acquiring' it. So I wanted to code whether the threads are really non blocking or not. **The updated code above**  *assigns 5 threads and 10 tasks to executor. All the threads which fail to acquire lock, go on to print the 'for' loop. That means they are "not busy waiting" while the lock-acquiring thread is working in 'critical section'*

In contrast I also implemented the synchronized way of doing it

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Synchronized extends Thread {

    static ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    static ArrayList<Object> toBeLocked = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public void methodA() {

        synchronized (toBeLocked) {
            try {
                System.out.println("lock acquired by " + this.getName() + "  of method A");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("this thread " + this.getName() + "was interrupted");
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Printed by " + this.getName() + " - " + i);
        }
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " is exiting at time " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        methodA();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable r = new Thread(new Synchronized());
            es.submit(r);
        }
        System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

}
```

**and found out that indeed all those threads were busy-waiting** . Now with the new way of doing it I observed that all the threads which failed to acquire lock went ahead and never cared about returning .Are there any design patterns that answer both, optimum use of thread pools and being able to notify the next most worthy candidate.